# Slow Mongo Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got a collection with about 200K documents.  Three properties are `verifed` (boolean),  `location` (geo coord) and `visited` (date).  Here's an example:

```
{
    "verified": true,
    "location": [ -79.4, 43.6 ],
    "visited": ISODate("2013-08-30T00:00:00Z")
    ... other properties
}
```

I have the following index:

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({
    verified: 1,
    location: '2dsphere',
    visited: -1
});
```

This index has the following size:

```
> db.coll.stats()
{
        "ns" : "mydb.coll",
        "count" : 181511,
        "size" : 2407550688,
        "avgObjSize" : 13263,
        "storageSize" : 2833022944,
        "numExtents" : 22,
        "nindexes" : 5,
        "lastExtentSize" : 536600560,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "systemFlags" : 0,
        "userFlags" : 1,
        "totalIndexSize" : 45507616,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 5347104,
                "verified_1_location_2dsphere_visited_-1" : 11658976,
                "TextIndex" : 28501536,
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Now, when I run the following query, it takes 50s (!) to execute:

```
db.coll.find({
    'verified': true,
    location: {
        $near: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [-79.5, 43.6]
            },
            $maxDistance: 2000
        }
    }
}).sort({
    visited: -1
});
```

Running `mongostat` at the same time suggests that the problem is page faults:

```
14:36:49 me@server ~> mongostat -n 200
connected to: 127.0.0.1
... lots of rows
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults         locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  3.73g  7.69g   135m     83 mydb:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     3k    12   14:41:20
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  3.73g  7.69g   136m     73 mydb:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     3k    12   14:41:21
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  3.73g  7.69g   136m     60 mydb:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     3k    12   14:41:22
     1     *0     *0     *0       0     2|0       0  3.73g  7.69g   137m     38 mydb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0   742b    35k    17   14:41:23
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  3.73g  7.69g   137m      0 mydb:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0    62b     3k    17   14:41:24
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  3.73g  7.69g   132m      0            .:0.3%          0       0|0
```

I would very much appreciate any help in interpreting these statistics.  My server isn't very powerful (1GB RAM), but given that the index is only 45M I really don't see why the whole index can't fit into memory.

Comment: It says that you have 3.73Gb mapped on a 1Gb machine

Comment: @Soren That's because my documents are big.  Are you saying that my data *and* indices have to fit into memory?

Comment: How many of the document will match the query? At least each of them would have to be pulled, and mango maps shards so your documents may be all over the database

Comment: @Soren About 3000 documents match the query, but limiting to say, 200, by adding a `.limit(200)` doesn't seem to have any effect on the performance. Limiting the fields returned also doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Limiting the fields would not help as it has to pull the entire document -- with 3000 documents returned there is a fair chance that it will have to access all the shards, and hence what comes in play is how big the sum of your shards are.  Not sure if the limit will optimize (reduce) the size of the query or if it only limits the output.

Comment: @Soren I'm not running a sharded database, and 3000 documents really doesn't sound like a crippling number to me.  Are you recommending reducing the size of my documents?  I could make a secondary collection with just the fields that this particular query requires...